# Entity Framework edmx NopCommerce 1.9

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am making a sample by exploring nopcommerce 1.9. I saw two things which i cannot understand First, I am not seeing "NopModel.Designer.cs" file in NopCommerce project and second t4 templates, how to generate these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually don't see the designer file associated with the EDMX file. If you want to view the XML code that is contained in the EDMX you can right click on it in the solution explorer and choose "Open With..." and then choose "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)" and it will let you view the XML code that is generated by VS when you add/create the EDMX file.

I don't believe that editing this code is suggested, as it is generated by VS and can be re-generated again for certain reasons which will wipe out any code that you may put there. Also if you change some code there it may break something.

I don't know why you're wanting T4 templates, but you can start here:

[How to create a simple T4 template](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-create-a-simple-t4-template/)